# How do I click a button and have it remove two things without knowing their ID or class values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The two things I'm talking about are a text field and a string that represents the HTML you would need to type to get that text field to appear. There's a button that makes those two things appear. Each time this button is clicked, another pair of the same kind appears.
But, each time a new pair is generated, I also have a button generated next to the text field that upon being clicked is supposed to delete the text field and the string that was created with it. So, how do I accomplish this?
I could program in "when button with class x1 is clicked, remove text field and string that also have class x1" and then "when button with class x2 is clicked, remove text field and string that also have class x2", and so on, but I mean a solution besides that.
Here's what the creation of the text field/HTML pair looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#textField').click(function() {
$('#codeBox').append('<div id="divText'+visText+'"><input type="text" class="textfield" maxlength="0" id="visText'+visText+'"><input type="button" value="O" id="o"> <input type="button" value="?" id="que"> <input type="button" value="X" id="closeX"><div id="textCode" class="codeDisplay"><div class="textCode">&lt;div&gt;&lt;input&nbsp;type="text"&nbsp;class="textfield"&nbsp;id="text'+textClicked+'"&lt;/div&gt;&lt;br&gt;</div></div>');

$('#codeBox2').append('&lt;div&gt;&lt;input&nbsp;type="text"&nbsp;class="textfield"&nbsp;id="text'+textClicked+'"&lt;/div&gt;&lt;br&gt;')
```

Comment: Please post some code for us to look at.

Comment: Please post generated code also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create elements dynamically, then you must have a reference to them from the code that creates them. When creating a button, add a `click` listener to it that uses these references via closure:

```
var text = document.createTextNode("some text");
var input = document.createElement("input");
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  text.parentElement.removeChild(text);
  input.parentElement.removeChild(input);
  button.parentElement.removeChild(button);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) to do that

Suppose you add something like this on click of "Add" button

```
<div>
        <div></div>
        <button class="remove">remove</button>
</div>
```

JS to remove

```
$(document).on("click", ".remove", function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

When you click remove, It will find its parent and remove it.

[JS Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/sKjNz/)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the various tree traversal methods of jquery: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal  that may help you remove the right elements when one of your remove buttons is clicked.